# What is the correct way to memset an array of pointers?

Tags: c++, c

If I have pointers of type `T (T*)` and I have an array of them `T* array[N]` will these two methods allow me to later check which entries are null pointers to lazily initialize stuff in each bucket?

`memset(array, 0, sizeof(T*)*N);`

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    array[i] = NULL;
```

i.e. will the `memset` call also let me later do `if (array[i] == NULL) ...`?

I wouldn't want to introduce undefined behavior if not..

Comment: The correct way is not to have that abomination in the first place in C++. Please, choose *either* C++ *or* C when asking a question like this.

Comment: Even in C there is another alternative: `T* array[N] = {NULL};`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although a null pointer value isn't technically required be all zero bits I'm not aware of any system where it's not all zero bits. So either method should work.

However there's an easier way to initialize an array which will set the correct null pointer values even on some evil implementation:

```
T *array[N] = {};
```

Or if you dynamically allocate it:

```
T **array = new T*[N]();
```

Comment: @Seth : The null _character_ must be represented with all zero bits (§2.3/3), but §3.9.2/3 says "*The value representation of pointer types is implementation-defined.*"

Answer (score 2):

Formally, the `memset` approach doesn't work, because there is no requirement that a null pointer be represented by the value `0` in memory. In practice it works fine.

Better than both: `std::uninitialized_fill`; the standard library implementor can do things that you can't to optimize performance.

Comment: *Can* != *will*. Still +1 for introducing me to [`std::uninitialized_fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_fill).

Comment: If you want to fill the array with null pointers, why would you prefer `std::uninitialized_fill` over `std::fill`?

Comment: @jamesdlin : A default-initialized array of pointers is in fact uninitialized, so `std::uninitialized_fill` is more pedantically correct even if unnecessary in this case.

Comment: Sweet I didnt' know of those!

Comment: @jamesdlin `std::uninitialized_fill` and `std::uninitialized_copy` use placement new to construct the elements they are initializing. `std::fill` and `std::copy` use assignment to already constructed objects. The difference is irrelevant to trivially constructible types such as pointers.

Comment: Well, you can either use `std::uninitialized_fill` and `std::fill` interchangeably when "[t]he difference is irrelevant" or you can use them consistently. The fact that the latter "works" when the underlying type is trivially constructible is pretty much a distraction. The true distinction is whether the memory has been initialized; if not, use `std::uninitialized_fill`; if so, use `std::fill`.

Comment: @PeteBecker In C++ `T array[N];` actually does 'initialize' the array and each element, using default initialization. I would argue that the distraction is in considering what `T` is in order to decide whether or not to use the placement new functions. Consider the generic case: do you actually want to specialize template code to use uninitialized_fill when you're given certain types? I believe that relying on the standard C++ object creation rules is better than special casing this, and that uninitialized_fill should be reserved for cases it is needed such as uses of aligned_storage.

Comment: @bames53 - it depends on where the array is defined. If it's auto or new'ed it doesn't get initialized. In the generic case, you **have to** choose one or the other, and you **have to** know what you're getting.

Comment: @PeteBecker Even arrays of automatic storage duration such as `int X[10];` and dynamic storage duration such as `int *X = new int[10];` are 'initialized'; C++ specifies that _default-initialization_ occurs. In the C++ object-lifetime model the element objects do exist. Here's an example of generic code vs. code specialized to use uninitialized_fill in the cases you seem to be advocating it for: http://ideone.com/3e4yX.

Comment: @bames53 - yes, I got carried away. What I'm "advocating" for is using `std::uninitialized_fill` for uninitialized memory and `std::fill` for initialized memory; that's what they're intended for. `std::uninitialized_fill` applies the **constructor** for the type; `std::fill` **assigns** to an existing object. Blurring the difference based on whether the target type has a trivial constructor doesn't gain anything.

Comment: @bames53 - thank you for explaining what I've already agreed to.

Comment: In short, the factor that should be considered when choosing to use uninitialized_fill over fill is the standard C++ object-lifetime model, which is consistent for all types and clearly visible in source code, and that we should not pay any attention to whether the memory is 'initialized', which differs between types and is a much more obscure and ambiguous issue. @jamesdlin